# Java Instruction Reordering/Cache In Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

Reading a book, and this code comes up:

```
public class Test {

    private static boolean ready = false;
    private static int number = 0;

    public static class ListenerThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {

            while(!ready) {
                Thread.yield();
            }
            System.out.println(number);

        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new ListenerThread().start();
        number = 10;
        ready = true;

    }

}
```

The main points I was surprised about were mentioned by the author relatively quickly.

1. They said ListenerThread might never terminate. I thought about this for a few days (in the back of my head), and my only conclusion is that it might be cached by that ListenerThread. Is that true? Would making `ready` volatile solve the problem (since it shouldn't cache it anymore)?
2. They also said the program might print 0. I understand now that Java might reorder the instructions, so ready becomes true to another thread before number is changed. Is there any method (technique), besides putting those instructions in a synchronized blocks solve the problem (on a central lock value)? I was thinking maybe implement notify()/wait(), but I feel it would suffer the same consequences. What is the best way to avoid the problem?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I just feel that I've read through a lot of code, and few bothered to protect against reordering in multiple threads. How common is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> my only conclusion is that it might be cached by that ListenerThread. Is that true? Would making ready volatile solve the problem (since it shouldn't cache it anymore)?

Not only cached, but the JIT can inline the value on the basis that the thread never changes it. i.e. it becomes hard coded.

Using volatile prevent such assumptions being made. It will force it to read a cache consistent copy each time.

> I understand now that Java might reorder the instructions,

Not only Java, but the CPU can re-order instructions.  The JIT is aware that the CPU can do this re-ordering and AFAIK it rarely needs to as it assumes the CPU will do a good job.

BTW Accessing a volatile variable also prevent instruction re-ordering so making `ready` volatile solves both problems.

Answer (score 3):

> They said ListenerThread might never terminate. I thought about this for a few days, and my only conclusion is that it might be cached by that ListenerThread. Is that true? Would making ready volatile solve the problem (since it shouldn't cache it anymore)?

That is true, yes. And yes, declaring the variable `volatile` changes the memory access semantics of the variable, and forces a reread each time the variable is accessed.

> They also said the program might print 0. I understand now that Java might reorder the instructions, so ready becomes true to another thread before number is changed. Is there any method, besides putting those two instructions in a synchronized blocks solve the problem? I was thinking maybe implement notify()/wait(), but I feel it would suffer the same consequences.

This is because there is no guarantee of *ordering*, so the JVM is free to reorder variable assignments. If you want to make `number` equally visible to both parties, you have to prevent this reordering, and as @PeterLawrey says, making `ready` volatile is enough for this.

Comment: The OP didn't mention synchronizing on `Test`, rather using `synchronized` blocks (possibly on some mutual lock which _would_ work).

Comment: @yair, yes, I thought of putting the ready check & print, and variable assignments in synchronized blocks on a random lock variable, but that would seem prohibitively  slow.

Comment: Yes, it was just unclear what the OP meant by "synchronized block". Editing.

Comment: @jsn it is probably way faster than an eyeblink ;)